# Ruby script for the url link only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

this is a ruby script for a photo with url link.

```
<%= if property.images[0] then
      link_to image_tag (property.images[0].image.url('350x263', :jpg)),                
      user_property_image_path(user, :id => property.images[0], :property_id => property),   

    end -%>
```

which part of script will only show url link without display the photo?
I tried this which is not work:

```
<%= user_property_image_path(user, :id => property.images[0], :property_id => property), 

end -%>
```

Comment: The code needs more context - e.g. the Rails view in question.

Comment: sorry, I can't access to the rails script.

Comment: Thanks for all the answer below, I tried all of the script provided, but none working for me. what I want is using the ruby to generate a link for a  text: <li><a href="#">More Photos</a></li>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will just render the link (without an image, and without redundantly specifying the URL twice):

```
<%= link_to( nil, user_property_image_path(user,
                                           :id => property.images[0],
                                           :property_id => property)) -%>
```

(You can pass nil as the first argument, and it will just link the URL that is generated.

Comment: thanks for that, I try it but it doesn't work. what I did is put your script on the # of <li><a href="#">More Photos</a></li>. then it showing error message. cheers

Answer (score 0):

This will display it with link text of *LINK TEXT HERE*:

```
<%= if property.images[0] then
      link_to 'LINK TEXT HERE',                
      user_property_image_path(user, :id => property.images[0], :property_id => property)    
    end -%>
```

If you want it to be the URL as the link text, try:

```
<% url = user_property_image_path(user, :id => property.images[0], :property_id => property) %>
<%= link_to( url, url ) if property.images[0] -%>
```

Comment: Here is some more documentation for that method - http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper/link_to. Your Rails skill will improve with your ability to peruse the documentation.

Comment: thanks for that, I try it but it doesn't work. what I did is put your script on the # of <li><a href="#">More Photos</a></li>. then it showing error message. cheers

Comment: You should just need to surround it with the <li></li> tags, the <a> tag is created by the link_to method. What error are you getting?

Answer (score 0):

this:

```
<% if property.images[0] %>
  <%= link_to user_property_image_path(user, :id => property.images[0], :property_id => property) do %>
    <%= image_tag (property.images[0].image.url('350x263', :jpg)) %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

achieves the same result as your first example. The HTML anchor tag needs inner content, either text or more html tags like img tags. Therefore, the link_to method, which renders anchor tags, will either receive the inner text as its first argument, or you can insert the inner content in its block, like exemplified above, which comes in handy if the content deemed linkable is somehow more complex.

To sum it up, you can't only render the link. You need to add content to this link.